# Create a new form group inside of the form group in the other component not in the one where the form was initialise in Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, dynamic

Trying to create a new form group inside of the existing form group in Angular 2. I define the main form in one of the component with the empty formGroup "type". I pass that formGroup "type" to another component. In that component I want to create a new formGroup with name "time", but it doesn't work. I didn't find any method in the FormGroup class for creating a new group. There is just methods for Controls for adding them to the FormGroup.

addControl method works but the next one not.

```
this.typeForm.addControl("gender", new FormControl('', Validators.required));
this.typeForm['time'] = this.fb.group({});
```

The FormBuilder should create something like:

```
{ 
  "name": "", 
  "type": {
           "gender": "",
           "time": {
                   }
          }
}
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to do something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
            name: [''],
            type: this.typeOptions()
        });
}

typeOptions(): FormGroup {
       return this.someService.getTypes().subscribe(
            res => {
                this.options = res.body;
            let obj: any = {};

            for (let option of options) {
                 let control: FormControl = new FormControl(option.value || '');
                 obj[option.title] = control;
            }

            return  new FormGroup(obj);
        }
    );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for sending a new idea how the problem could be implemented. At the end I implemented it in the way that I use method addControl and pass new FormGroup as a param.

Comment: Beware, as written, the `typeOptions` method returns an `Observable<void>`, not a `FormGroup`. This answer should be completely reworked in order to work...